# I want to write a unix code to extract all the column names between the parentheses from this SQL code which is in a .txt file

Tags: shell, unix

i want to write a dynamic code in unix which will extract any number of column names contained in the parentheses.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(
   `id` int,
   `name` string,
   `email` string,
   `signup` date)
SPLIT BY (
   `country` string)
CLUSTERED BY (
   name)
```

Expected output would be:

```
(
   `id` int,
   `name` string,
   `email` string,
   `signup` date)
```

Comment: Why do you specify "using grep" as part of the question? If someone can write cleaner (or more portable, insofar as `grep -o` is a GNUism) code using, say, awk or sed, why are you writing the question in such a way as to reject that answer before it's written?

Comment: BTW, it looks like what you're asking for is *column* names, not *table* names.

Comment: extremely sorry about that, its my first time posting a question, i would edit and make it clear.

Comment: Do you need to properly handle all possible legal SQL syntax, or only the subset shown in the question (with linebreaks at the same place)?

Comment: i dont mind about the linebreaks or the syntax, i just want to get the column names extracted.

Comment: Are you saying you don't mind if they're wrong *in the output*? Because that isn't what I was trying to ask; I'm asking if they're guaranteed to be consistent with what you show *in the input*, or if the code also needs to correctly extract column names even if the input is differently-formatted.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example that works *for your specific input* might look like:

```
printing=0
create_table_start_re='CREATE[[:space:]]+TABLE[[:space:]]+[^(]+([(].*)'
close_paren_re='^(.*[)])'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $create_table_start_re ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    printing=1
    continue
  elif (( printing == 0 )); then
    continue
  elif [[ $line =~ $close_paren_re ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    printing=0
  else
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
  fi
done
```

...as you can see working correctly with your sample input at https://ideone.com/bgxfht

However, by no means does that work correctly for all possible valid SQL! If you want something that can parse SQL DDL, you should use a real built-to-purpose parser, not hack something up with line-oriented text-processing tools.